# Using an Azure portal generated SAS in C# Azure.Data.Tables client library

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage, shared-access-signatures

I have generated a Shared Access Signature in the Azure portal. It gives me three strings: `Connection string`, `SAS token`, and `Table service SAS URL`. I would have thought that I could take the value of `Connection string` which contains the value of the `SAS token` prefixed by a url and create a new `TableClient` and query my table but it doesn't work.

**Please note:** I'm using `Azure.Data.Tables 12.8.0`

```cs
TableClient tc = new TableClient("<value-of-Connection-string>", "<my-table-name>");
var data = tc.Query<MyPoco>();    // I realize this is a table scan but don't care until it works
```

This returns error:

```
RequestFailedException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.
RequestId:dfe1fbe6-XXXX-002d-7997-XXXXXXXXXXXX
Time:2023-03-14T17:09:53.0004938Z
Status: 403 (Forbidden)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share what the SAS token/URL looks like? Also, just to confirm you are using SAS URL for connection string in your code. Right?

Comment: @GauravMantri, `Table service SAS URL` looks like `https://<mycontainer>.table.core.windows.net/?sv=xxx&ss=yyy&sig=zzz&spr=uuu...`. If I use the value of this as the connection string I get error: `Connection string parsing error`.

Comment: `Connection string` looks like: `BlobEndpoint=...;TableEndpoint=https://<mycontainer>.table.core.windows.net...;SharedAccessSignature=sv=xxx&ss=yyy&sig=zzz&spr=uuu...`

Comment: You cannot use SAS token in connection string.

Comment: Then I do not know how to supply the SAS token to the `TableClient` and query my table.

Comment: Added an answer with 2 options. Please give them a try. HTH.

Comment: Argh! I assumed that allowing Container resource type also implied Object resource types but obviously not! If I check Object resource type and pass `Connection string` to `TableClient` it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use SAS URL to create an instance of `TableClient`, please use the following constructor: [`TableClient(Uri, TableClientOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#azure-data-tables-tableclient-ctor(system-uri-azure-data-tables-tableclientoptions)) where the URI is the SAS URL of the table in `https://account.table.core.windows.net/table-name?sas-token` format.

Other alternative would be to use the following constructor: [`TableClient(Uri, AzureSasCredential, TableClientOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#azure-data-tables-tableclient-ctor(system-uri-azure-azuresascredential-azure-data-tables-tableclientoptions)) where URI is the base URI of the table in `https://account.table.core.windows.net/table-name` format and `AzureSasCredential` is something you would create with your SAS token using something like:

```
var credentials = new AzureSasCredential(sasToken);
var tableClient = new TableClient(new Uri("https://account.table.core.windows.net/table-name"), credentials);
```